# Camera not closing while using open cv in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am creating a funtion liveCapture() to take a photo and save it in the local directory.
The function is working fine and the photo is also saved perfectly but even after the execution, my web cam isn't closing. Following is the snippet

```
import cv2
import numpy

def liveCapture()->None:

    camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    rec,captured=camera.read()

    cv2.imwrite("photo.jpg",captured)

    camera.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

liveCapture()
```